# Grails + Netbeans + Apache Tomcat

Tags: grails, http-status-code-404

So I have my grails server running with netbeans and i'm codding new features / testing in my browser at same time. For some reason, sometimes when i change code im domain classes and then save and refresh my page, the server seems to go down but in reality, it is still running. I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0-snapshot
```

Any idea how to solve that? Because its really anoying, i make changes and then when i want to visualize it the server goes down. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: How are you deploying? `grails run-app` or are you making a `grails war` and copying to the `webapps` folder in Tomcat?

Comment: i'm using netbeans. The grails project is running while i change the code.

Comment: I've never run a Grails project through NetBeans. Do you have the same problem if you modify the code after a `grails run-app` from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change anything in a domain class and save it your app will get re-deployed and may take a minute (404 in the meantime).  You can change views and controllers without the app being re-deployed and you should see the changes as soon as you save and refresh.

Does this help?